# When is the following process stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

Let $Y$ be a random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, and let $c$ be a constant. Let $$X_t = Y\cos(ct)$$
When is the process $X_t$ stationary?

I find $E(X_t) = \cos(ct)E(Y) = 0$

$E(X_tX_{t+\tau}) = E(Y^2\cos(ct)\cos(ct+c\tau)) = \cos(ct)\cos(ct+c\tau)E(Y^2)$

Note that $Var(Y) = E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2 \implies E(Y^2) = Var(Y) = \sigma^2$

Then, using the sum and product formula for cosine, we get $$E(X_tX_{t+\tau})= \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(\cos(2ct+c\tau)+\cos(c\tau)) $$

Now, as I understand it, in order for this process to be stationary, we require $E(X_tX_{t+\tau})$ to be only a function of $\tau$. So is the process only stationary when $c=0$? This doesn't seem to be correct based on the proceeding questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let us observe the situation when $\tau=0$. The expectation of $X_t^2$ should not depend on $t$ hence we should have either $\sigma=0$ or $\cos^2\left(ct\right)=1$ for all $t$. The last condition forces $c$ to be a multiple of $\pi$.

Conversely, we can check that if $\sigma=0$ or $c\in \pi\mathbb Z$ then $\left(X_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb Z}$ is weakly stationary. In the first case $X_t=0$ and in the second, $X_t=\left(-1\right)^t Y$.

Comment: I agree that the expectation of $X_t^2$ should not depend on $t$, so we can either have $\sigma = 0$ or $\cos^2(ct) = \text{constant}\; \forall t$. Why must this constant be $1$? Also, is it normally assumed that $t\in \mathbb{Z}$? I'm new to time series, so I'm unsure.

Comment: The constant should be 1 because it should coincide with the value at 0. The time series can also be indexed by the set of non-negative integers.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand why the constant must be $1$. Although I don't know the justification behind why we can change what is potentially a real valued time index, into an integer one?